# Scala import packageName.ClassName VS import package._ overhead?

Tags: scala, import, compilation

I am new to scala and this might come from java world..
In scala you can do:

```
import packageName.className
```

Or if you wish to import all classes in that package

```
import packageName._
```

What happens here ? when the solution is being compiled ?
I assume in my own classes, each package contains maybe 10-20 classes so there is no effect, but what happens when i do:  **import play.api._**

1. Is it going to take longer for the solution to be built?
2. Is there any performance issues ? the application size in the end will be in the same size i assume since it is referenced to the same package and includes all the classes inside it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No for both questions.

As Scala comes from Java world, the importing rules are the same.

There are two import types:

`import play.api.Controller` is called a **single type import**

`import play.api._` is called **import on demand**

Both these imports are passive i.e. they load information only when needed (when the type is actually used) and not when the type is just imported. Imports tell the compiler where to look for types when they are needed.

So importing the entire package instead of importing a single type produces no overhead.

One more thing to tell, look at the Scala or Java APIs - there are lots of classes with the same names.

Imagine you need to use `play.Logger` and `play.api.Controller` and write imports like this:

```
import play._
import play.api._
```

Now you will have a collision on both `Logger` and `Controller` types because they exist in both packages. Importing specific classes will save you from this issue.

Comment: Just to add a little to your answer to make things more clear for @ilansch: In Java and in Scala importing additional classes does not increase compiled unit size neither it should significantly affect compilation time. It's not like `#include` in C where all the source code is being copy pasted in place of `include`. However, by importing with wildcard you are polluting the namespace and make it less clear what classes are actually used.